# how to crypto api for writing kernel module

Tags: linux, module, kernel, cryptoapi

I want to write a small kernel module in which I have to take a static string, hex-encode it and then use arc4 algorithm to encrypt it and then reverse the process. The logic is pretty clear to me. What I am suffering is that of a guideline of using the crypto api. I cannot exactly find the way out. If some one can give me a rough introduction or a useful link, it will be of much help to me. I searched a lot about it, but could not figure it out exactly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by kernel module?

Comment: I meant linux kernel module. And I found the way out by looking examples inside the linux kernel code.

Comment: great, if you answer your post then it might help someone!